# mixed curvatures on a totally geodesic submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Recently, when I read a paper, I meet a question: Suppose $S$ is a totally geodesic submanifold in $M$. $p\in S$, $u\in T_pS$ and $v\in T_pM\cap (T_pS)^{\perp}$. Then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
R(u,v)v&\in T_pS;\\
R(v,u)u&\in T_pM\cap (T_pS)^{\perp};\\
\end{aligned}
$$
I tried to write down the concrete expression $R(u,v)v=D_uD_vv-D_vD_uv-D_{[u,v]}v$ and show it lies in $T_pS$ from the vanishing of the second fundamental form. But I can't solve it.  Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: What do you mean by totally geodesic submanifold?

Comment: I mean that the second fundamental form vanishes along the submanifold.